# C++11 - Possible dilemma with pimpl-idiom and unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, linker, unique-ptr

As I was trying to take advantage of pimpl-idiom and smart pointers to implement my own wrapper around platform-specific GUI components, I encountered a problem I'm unable to solve. The problem is probably with pimpl-idiom and *unique_ptr*, since I don't know what else could be wrong. All errors seem to be linking errors. I get various undefined reference errors while using the code (link below):
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/96020/

Here is the list of errors:

```
> obj\debug_windows\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.o||In
> function `Window':|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\test2\test2\..\..\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window.hpp|15|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper>
> >::PointerSmartSafe(HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper*)'| E:\new2\projects\programming\test2\test2\..\..\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window.hpp|15|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper>
> >::PointerSmartSafe(HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper> > const&)'|
> obj\debug_windows\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.o||In
> function `Window':|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|88|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper>
> >::PointerSmartSafe(HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper*)'| E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|91|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper>
> >::PointerSmartSafe(HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper*)'| obj\debug_windows\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.o||In
> function `ZN15HelixirrWidgets6Window12save_changesEv':|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|98|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper> >::operator->()
> const'|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|100|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper> >::operator->()
> const'|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|101|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper> >::operator->()
> const'|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|106|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper> >::operator->()
> const'|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|107|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper> >::operator->()
> const'|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|109|undefined
> reference to `GetStockObject@4'|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|111|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper> >::operator->()
> const'|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|112|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper> >::operator->()
> const'|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|114|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper> >::operator->()
> const'|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|118|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper> >::operator->()
> const'|
> E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|119|undefined
> reference to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper> >::operator->()
> const'|
> obj\debug_windows\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.o:E:\new2\projects\programming\helixirrwidgets\src\helixirrwidgets\Window-windows.cpp|120|more
> undefined references to
> `HelixirrWidgets::PointerSmartSafe<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper,
> std::default_delete<HelixirrWidgets::Window::Helper> >::operator->()
> const' follow| ||=== Build finished: 16 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem does not have anything to do with the PIMPL idiom, nor with the fact that you are using `std::unique_ptr<>`.

Rather, it seems your code does not `#include` the `PointerSmartSafe.inl` file, which contains the definitions for all the member functions of the `PointerSmartSafe<>` class template.

Therefore, the compiler won't be able to implicitly instantiate those functions when calls to them are encountered, and those functions are not instantiated in `PointerSmartSafe.inl` either (only defined).

Therefore, the linker will complain that those symbols are not found. If you need more details, you may find [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) quite informative.

---

To fix the problem, add an:

```
#include "PointerSmartSafe.hpp"
```

directive at the beginning of `PointerSmartSafe.inl`, and let all translation units which currently `#include` the `PointerSmartSafe.hpp` header `#include` the `PointerSmartSafe.inl` file instead.

Or, if you want to make this simpler, just move the content of `PointerSmartSafe.inl` at the end of `PointerSmartSafe.hpp`, and at that point you can even delete the `PointerSmartSafe.inl` file.

Comment: Thank you so much, Andy! Problem solved. Funny how such a small mistake can cause so much headache! Your name shall be put into source code for helping me out. God bless you.

Comment: I'm happy when you are. :)